# If $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

let $X=\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E}2^{-n}$

How to show:

If $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly.

Could you please help.

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $\varepsilon$, pick $N$ such that $\sum_{n\geqslant N}2^{-n}\lt\varepsilon$. The convergence on $\{1,\dots,N\}$ is uniform while $\mathbb N
\setminus\{1,\dots,N\}$ has a measure smaller than $\varepsilon$.